# What is the name of this solitaire variant?

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

[image: solitaire]

I recently learned a new solitaire from a friend, but we have no idea what the name of it is. Can anyone help?

You use two decks of cards, and start by placing 14 rows of cards. The middle 4 rows are laid horizontal and are locked. The rest of the cards are placed vertical and are open. All of the cards are placed face-up. The rest of the cards are left in a pile with the face down and drawn one-after-one as you need them. (The bottom card is also open, but not sure if that's a rule my friend started with or not.)

The game is very similar to Klondike as you're supposed to build from kings down to ace with different color for each card (red on black or black on red). Then you gather all the aces and build up on them. The difficult part of this solitaire is that the locked cards in the middle have to be placed in one of the ace piles before you can use it up in the main game again.

I hope my explanation isn't too difficult to understand. If anyone knows the name, please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Apologize for the bad picture, but hope you get it.

Comment: [Take a look through this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Double_deck_solitaire_card_games)

Comment: can you provide a picture?

Comment: Will provide picture as soon as I have card decks available.

Comment: In [official terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Patience_terms), there is a 10 by 5 main tableau, a 4 by 5 secondary tableau, eight foundation spots, a stock, and a discard pile.  The goal is to build up in sequence by alternating color.  Cards from the secondary tableau must first be played directly to a foundation.  (Or something like that.)

Comment: It's possible that this is simply a two-deck version of some other variant, with two "locked" piles and 5 unlocked ones.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like stalactites. ( [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalactites_(solitaire)), [Double Deck Version](https://www.solsuite.com/games/stalactites_and_stalagmites.htm) )

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games! Your answer would be much better if it contained a (short) explanation of the rules; right now it has been flagged as low quality. Links to external sites may break, that's why.